# Xubuntu slow login, unable to go back to login screen. How to debug?

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, xorg, xubuntu, login-screen

Fresh Xubuntu install (enabling TwinView in Nvidia's propietary drivers) is suddenly taking too long to login after I enter my credentials in the login screen. When I log out (trying to go back to the login screen) all I get is a black screen.

I don't know where to start, because I'm not really sure which program's guilty of the slowdown. How could I debug this?

This is my xorg.conf (autogenerated by Nvidia X Server Settings), in case it helps:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    Screen      1  "Screen1" RightOf "Screen 0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "HP w1907"
    HorizSync       24.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     50.0 - 76.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"

    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "SAMSUNG"
    HorizSync       26.0 - 68.0
    VertRefresh     24.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 460"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
    Screen         0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 460"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
    Screen         1
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "TwinView" "1"
    Option         "TwinViewXineramaInfoOrder" "CRT-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "CRT: nvidia-auto-select +0+0, DFP: nvidia-auto-select +1440+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "TwinView" "0"
    Option         "TwinViewXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-2"
    Option         "metamodes" "DFP: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Extensions"
    Option         "Composite" "Enable"
EndSection
```

Answer (score 1):

I edited `/usr/share/gvfs/mounts/network.mount` by running:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/gvfs/mounts/network.mount
```

Then I made the `[Mount]` section look like this:

```
[Mount]
Type=network
Exec=/usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-network
AutoMount=false
```

*In particular, I did this by changing the value of `AutoMount` from `true` to `false`.*

Comment: This seems completely unrelated.